# How to pass date as parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass date today in javaScript function as a parameter, How I can do it?
This is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendDate()"></button>
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more showing what you have done so far along with an explanation as to what it is doing (or not doing) and what you expect it to do?
Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can look up how to get the current date in JavaScript, right? Then you know how to pass a function argument, or no?

Comment: I know these things that you said

Comment: Just I want to pass today date in javaScript function

Comment: <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendDate(new Date())"></button>

this is pass the date and I want to pass today date in this parameter

Comment: @Sohrab Why does `sendDate(new Date())` (as per your previous comment) not work?

Comment: @MTCoster I solved that thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to pass the object you can use:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendDate(new Date())"></button>
```

But, you can use new Date() to get current date-time in the javascript method as well.